# What is the actionlist item for Open Recent.. in JetBrains IdeaVim?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I have been looking at [this `:actionlist` dump](https://gist.github.com/zchee/9c78f91cc5ad771c1f5d) for IdeaVim for a while now, and am unable to figure out which action corresponds to `Open Recent` (project) in JetBrains. This is the specific action I am looking at:

[image: clion screenshot]

I wanted to be able to reassign a `<leader>` based keystroke to this action in `~/.ideavimrc`. So, how exactly should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID for the `open recent` action is a bit unusual `$LRU`. You should map the leader keystroke to `:action $LRU`.